# ffmpeg convert mov to mp4 without reduction of bit rate

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, codec

I am trying to convert a mov video to mp4, but I don't want any compression to happen. I recorded it with Quicktime on a Mac and did so with maximum, uncompressed quality. When I run `ffmpeg -i`. I get:

```
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1280x720, 72073 kb/s, 30.09 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
```

Note the kb/s is 72,073. I want to preserve this bit rate.

I've tried a few different conversion commands, including:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4
```

and:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -qscale 0 output.mp4
```

Both work, but both result in a loss of bit rate. See info on the results of both

```
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p, 1280x720, 4569 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
```

How do I convert to mp4 and still have ~72,000 kb/s? Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're comparing apples to oranges. ProRes and H.264 are two completely different formats, so comparing bitrates is meaningless. What you're really asking is...

### How to convert ProRes to H.264 (MP4) with no quality loss?

Just set the quality with `-crf`. A value of `0` is lossless, and `18` looks lossless but really isn't.

#### Visually lossless

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -crf 18 output.mp4
```

#### Lossless

Output file will be huge, and your player may not like it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -crf 0 output.mp4
```

#### Compatibility

If you need the output to be playable in non-FFmpeg based players add `-vf format=yuv420p` :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -crf 18 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

- You may notice a slight reduction in color fidelity, but it is required for wide compatibility.
- You can omit `-vf format=yuv420p` if you're uploading to YouTube.

#### Stream copy

ProRes is not compatible in MP4, so you can't just do a [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (like a copy and paste). However, for those finding to this question, and who have compatible formats, and want to just change the container from MOV to MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy output.mp4
```

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: apologies for necroposting, but I'm curious about your note about "Lossless". why would my player not like it? if the player can deal with upwards of 20+ gb of footage in an MP4, why would a MOV converted to an MP4 be hard to deal with?